# For $n!=2^ab$, prove that $a<n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory

Write $n!=2^ab$ where $b,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{N}  \cup \{0\}$. Prove that $a<n$.

The value $a$ is the maximum value that satisfies the equality, consequently this means that $b$ is odd.

Comment: you have to provide some context indicating your level of understanding of the question. This is particularly helpful for potential answerers.

Answer (score 4):

By Legendre's formula, the exponent $\alpha$ of $2$ in $n!$ is $\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lfloor{n/2^k}\rfloor\leqslant n\sum_{k=1}^\infty1/2^k=n,$ and as $\alpha\geqslant a$ then $a\leqslant n$ (the strict inequality occurs only when $b$ is even).

Comment: Can't stop myself from saying how much I like the clarity and simplicity of this argument ;)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you are right, I didn't pay attention to that "little" detail

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: the way the OP states the question indicates that this should be proved for the max possible value of $a$. Which happens when $b$ is odd.

Comment: @KonKan: No, the statement of the problem does not specify that $b$ is odd. What *is* true, of course, is that it suffices to prove the result for the maximum possible value of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that the number of factors of $2$ in $n!$ is

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\;.$$